# Python-Markdown in Voila

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I would like to render the nbextension [python-markdown](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/python-markdown) in [voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila).

Currently

```
a = 1.23
```

in a jupyter-code cell
and

```
a is {{a}}
```

in a jupyter-markdown cell is rendered when executing in jupyter-notebook, but not in voila. Do I need here additional plugins or is that feature not yet deployed ?

Comment: I think Voila only renders widgets and plain markdown mainly. It looks like from [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/469), that work is going on to get other extensions that add other features. As Voila is now under the Jupyter 'umbrella', it may be wise to make a brief post at [the Jupyter discourse forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) pointing to this fully fleshed version of your question to get more eyes it here.